# How do I make Visual Studio 2012's title bar change color on selection?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, titlebar

With Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft has apparently abandoned the very useful UI convention of "having any visual distinction whatsoever between a selected and unselected window, so the user can actually tell where the hell their input will appear when they start typing". Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

After asking around my office, I discovered that this is changeable in the Theme Editor extension. Microsoft calls the title bar "Main Window -> Caption", just to ensure the setting is impossible to find.

Comment: Presumably you mean the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05)

Comment: This solution still works for Visual Studio 2017 with the [2017 theme editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor)